# WordPress add field

Tags: wordpress

I would like to add a select field in `admin/post-new.php`.
This select field will be populated with JSON data (from a GET URL).

^ This point is solved. In your function.php:

```
function acf_load_colors_field_choices($field) {
    $field['choices'] = [];

    $choices = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://127.0.0.1/json/colors'), true);

    if (is_array($choices)) {
         foreach ($choices as $choice) {
            $field['choices'][$choice] = $choice;
         }
    }

    return $field;
}

add_filter('acf/load_field/name=colors', 'acf_load_colors_field_choices');
```

Once the page is ready to be published, I would like to catch POST data to send them to another URL.

How to catch those data?

Answer (score 0):

In functions.php, to catch POST data:

```
function on_save_post_articles($post_id) {
    var_dump($post_id);
    var_dump($_POST);
    exit;
}

add_action('save_post', 'on_save_post_articles');
```

Solved!